# What is the sum of a generalised gamma variable and a normal variable?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $G\sim \mathcal{GG}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ and $N\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then what is $G+N$? Can it even exist since the two distributions have different support?

I have tried to solve this two ways using a convolution, but get stuck on the integrals.

The first is to take a standard convolution

\begin{align*}
f_{G+N}(x)&=\int_{0}^{\infty} f_N(x-y)f_G(y)dy\\
&=C_1\int_0^{\infty}y^{\beta-1}e^{-C_2 (x-y-\mu)^2-C_3y^\gamma}dy
\end{align*}
but this integral is difficult to solve (Mathematica has no solutions).

The other is to see that you can write $G=|N^*|^p$ where $N^*$ is normal. Then
\begin{align*}
f_{|N^*|^p+N}(x)&=\int_0^{\infty} f_{N^*}(x-|y|^p)f_N(y)dy\\
&=C_1\int_0^{\infty} e^{-C_2(x-|y|^p-\mu_{N^*})^2-C_3(y-\mu)^2}dy
\end{align*}
but this integral is also very difficult to solve (Mathematica fails once again).

If there is a suggestion regarding the integrals, or a known result regarding the main question, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by "What is $G+N$?"  It's a random variable.  As you mentioned, you can use the convolution to find its pdf, even if it doesn't exist in closed form.  What more do you want to be able to say about it?

Comment: Why do you think that a closed form exists?  If it doesn't exist, you shouldn't blame *Mathematica* or any other software for that.

Comment: @user6247850 I was hoping to solve the integral in order to find the pdf and, ideally, whether there is a known distribution with some standard results which I can use. 

@ JimB I am not sure if a closed form exists, although the sum of GG variables is a Fox-H function, which is not a closed form, so I suspect that a closed form does not exist. However, the Mathematica library includes Fox-H functions and hypergeometric functions, neither of which are closed form, and are the sort of functions I would expect to find as solutions to these integrals.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extended comment in that using `Assumptions` in *Mathematica* will find the pdf of the sum for $\gamma=1$ and $\gamma=2$.

```
Integrate[E^(-((x - y - μ)^2/(2 σ^2)))/(Sqrt[2 π] σ)*
  (E^-(y/β)^γ (y/β)^(-1 + α γ) γ)/(β Gamma[α]) /. {γ -> 1}, 
  {y, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {σ > 0, α > 0, β > 0}]
```

[image: pdf of sum with gamma = 1]

```
Integrate[E^(-((x - y - μ)^2/(2 σ^2)))/(Sqrt[2 π] σ)*
  (E^-(y/β)^γ (y/β)^(-1 + α γ) γ)/(β Gamma[α]) /. {γ -> 2}, 
  {y, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {σ > 0, α > 0, β > 0}]
```

[image: pdf of sum with gamma = 2]

There might be other special cases.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was already aware of some special cases for $\beta=\frac{1}{2}$, $\beta=1$ and $\beta=2$. Unfortunately, in my case each of the parameters of my GG variable depend on the eigenvalues of a dynamical system, which I want to vary. The only fair assumption is $\gamma=2\beta$.